# jquery datepicker enable all sunday except first sunday of month

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to enable all future sunday except first sunday of every month in
jquery ui datepicker. Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: Please show what you've tried. You just need to use the `beforeShowDay:` option to enable and disable the days that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want:-

```
$("#datestart").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
      var first_week = date.getDate();   
      return  first_week <= 7 && day == 0?[false, '']:[true,''];       
    }
  });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m443no17/4/)**

Comment: yeah great Mohit. and also if want disable all days except sunday with disable first sunday how can i change the condition? could you say?

Comment: nice Mohit. would be great answer what i expect. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay)

```js
$('input').datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var dt = date.getDate();
    return [!(date.getDay() == 0 && date.getDate() <= 7)]
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input />
```